# C++ Winsock programming, receiving no response from HTTP protocol

Tags: c++, sockets, http, tcp, ip

As the title says, I've just began studying how the TCP/IP protocol applies to C++, so I tried sending a packet to any random website (In this case www.nasa.gov), using the IP address (DNS Resolver) and a random port (I went for 80), and I am receiving no answer. I have no idea if the code is wrong, because as far as I can tell it is correct:
If the code is correct, is it something about using a different port(because I've tried 0,27, and 80), or ? I've also tried sending a packet to 127.0.0.1, so I could capture it through Wireshark easily, but nothing showed up. Sometimes, when using this program to send packets to a random website, I get a weird answer that I can't emulate again.

```
#pragma     comment(lib,"Ws2_32.lib")

#include    <iostream>
#include    <winsock2.h>
#include    <windows.h>
#include    <string>
#include    <fstream>

#define     SCK_VERSION2    0x0202

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //File buffer
    ofstream buf;
    buf.open("message.txt");

    //All the important stuff
    long SUCCESFUL;
    WSAData WinSockData;
    WORD DLLVersion;
    DLLVersion = MAKEWORD(2,1);
    SUCCESFUL = WSAStartup(DLLVersion, &WinSockData);
    char ip[] = "255.255.255.255";
    short unsigned int port;
    cout << "Insert an IP to connect to : ";
    cin >> ip;
    cout << "\nInsert a port to connect to: ";
    cin >> port;
    char message[] = "GET http://www.nasa.gov/index.html HTTP/1.1"
"Host: www.nasa.gov"
"Accept: */*"
"Accept-Language: en-us"
"Connection: keep-alive"
"User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)";

    string RESPONSE,
           CONVERTER;
    char MESSAGE[200];

    SOCKADDR_IN ADDRESS;

    SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);

    ADDRESS.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);  
    ADDRESS.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ADDRESS.sin_port = htons(port);

    cout << "\nDo You want to connect to " << ip << ":" << port << "? (Y/N)";
    cin >> RESPONSE;

    RESPONSE[0] = tolower(RESPONSE[0]);
    if(RESPONSE[0] == 'n')
        cout << "\nNot connecting.";
    else if(RESPONSE[0] == 'y')
    {
        cout << "\nSending...";
        connect(sock, (SOCKADDR*)&ADDRESS, sizeof(ADDRESS));
        send(sock,message,sizeof(message),NULL);
        SUCCESFUL = recv(sock, MESSAGE,sizeof(MESSAGE),NULL);
        CONVERTER = MESSAGE;
        cout << "\nMessage: " << hex << CONVERTER;
        cout << "\nDone.";
    }
    for(unsigned short int loop = 0; loop < 200; loop++)
        buf << CONVERTER;
    buf.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're missing all line breaks and sending data in one line. It won't work

Comment: If you're talking about using this kind of thing: `"Accept-Language: en-us"
"Connection: keep-alive"` , it does work. Or do you mean that each line has to be sent separately?

Comment: That is identical to "Accept-Language: en-usConnection: keep-alive", which is incorrect. HTTP requires CRLF in between and two in the end of the request

Comment: Wireshark on Windows requires some extending to see local host packets.

Comment: @user4581301: or you can use a custom ROUTE to bounce local packets off a network router back to the localhost so Wireshark can capture them normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTTP protocol requires all header lines to be ended with CRLF and an empty line to follow. You have all header lines without any line breaks.

```
char message[] = "GET http://www.nasa.gov/index.html HTTP/1.1"
    "Host: www.nasa.gov"
    "Accept: */*"
    "Accept-Language: en-us"
    "Connection: keep-alive"
    "User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)";
```

This is equal to

```
char message[] = "GET http://www.nasa.gov/index.html HTTP/1.1Host: www.nasa.govAccept: */*...
```

You need to separate them

```
char message[] = "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n"
    "Host: www.nasa.gov\r\n"
    "Accept: */*\r\n"
    "Accept-Language: en-us\r\n"
    "Connection: keep-alive\r\n"
    "User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)\r\n"
    "\r\n";
```

Also note the two CRLFs in the end.

For testing purposes I would also suggest not using keep-alive to make it simpler.

You also have a strange loop outputing the same response string 200 times in the end, but that doesn't affect the actual request.

Comment: The 200 character cap is to make sure everything fits in, I don't think it should be a problem, but I will try and let you know if it works

Comment: You also need to change the `GET` line to `GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n`, and then send the HTTP request to the IP address of `www.nasa.gov` itself. Use `gethostbyname()` or `getaddrinfo()` to get that IP, don't make the user enter it manually.  The original `GET` line shown would only work if sending the HTTP request to an HTTP proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with your code - You are trying to connect to

```
ADDRESS.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);  
ADDRESS.sin_family = AF_INET;
ADDRESS.sin_port = htons(port);
```

Where `ip` is

```
char ip[] = "255.255.255.255";
```

Which means - you are trying to 'connect' to a broadcast address on port 80. I think you should get a `Connection Refused` error.

Note: simply Having a line `Host: www.nasa.gov` is not sufficient to connect to www.nasa.gov. You have to first do a name resolution for that using something line `getaddrinfo`. But I'd suggest - since you seem to be learning - a good idea is to do an `nslookup` on the command line (command prompt `cmd`) and then use the returned IP in your `ip` above. Next step would be to use `getaddrinfo`.

Also a good idea to check whether `connect` succeeded and do `send` etc only upon connect success. If `connect` fails - a good idea is to print the error.

This plus other issues mentioned in HTTP Header should get you started.

Comment: `cout << "Insert an IP to connect to : ";
    cin >> ip;`
So that is not a problem. The problem was the message, and thank you for the tips :)